# Create a folder in google drive php

Tags: php, directory, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Is there any way we could create a folder on google drive using PHP? I've been searching all the web for the last 72 hours with no results.
What do you think guys?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you read this? https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php

Comment: or this: https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Creating a Folder:

"In the Drive API, a folder is essentially a file — one identified by the special folder MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder. You can create a new folder by inserting a file with this MIME type and a folder title. Do not include an extension when setting a folder title.

To create a subfolder to a particular folder, specify the the correct ID in the parents property of the file. For example, to create the folder "pets" in an "images" folder whose id value is 0ADK06pfg:"

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json
...
{
  "title": "pets",
  "parents": [{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}]
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/folder

Examples: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php

Comment: Thank you bro, it was really that simple , I remember reading this when going through the API , but didn't give it that importance. Thanks in again Paul, it worked :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is an updated method using the Google Drive API v3 and an OAuth access token:

```
$googleClient = new \Google_Client();
$googleClient->setApplicationName('My App');
$googleClient->setAccessToken(env('GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'));
$googleClient->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_APP_ID'));
$googleClient->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_APP_SECRET'));

if ($googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken();
}

$api = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('Folder Name');
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

$folder = $api->files->create($file);
```

This uses the Google Client Library

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference